# Java Binary Search <Identifier expected>

Tags: java

I had a question regarding my binary search code.

```
 public static Pair binarySearchDup(ArrayList<Integer> A, int x, int low, int high)
```

The error I keep receiving is telling me that at my if and else statements, I need an identifier for my lines of code

for example

if(A.[mid] == x)

It is saying that I need an identifier between . and [mid].

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

There should be no dot when you are referencing an item in an array. Your expression should be

`if (A[mid] == x)`

The dot operator refers to something that is a method of an object. For arrays, it is not used.